# retrieving gpg key timed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to run the following command and get this error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

I have my firewall turned off and did the proceeding commands before running this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :80
```

if nginx is listening on port 80

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

then I follow with the command:

```
sudo apt-get-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

and get the following errors;

```
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out
```

Any help??

Answer (score 7):

The problem is likely to be the GPG keyserver you are connecting to being overloaded. You can probably try again later, or if that still does not work, you can switch to a different keyserver.

For example, if you would like to use `keys.openpgp.org` as your keyserver, you can put

```
keyserver keys.openpgp.org
```

into `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a VPN and your problem would be solved.